# Problems performing on Linux this Spring application that upload a file on an FTP server by Spring Integration FTP: MessagingException

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I am pretty new in Spring and I have the following situation.

I have implemented a simple console Spring application that perform the upload of a file into an FTP server using Spring Integration FTP project: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html

So I have:

1) **MainApp** class:

```
public class MainApp {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

      HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

      obj.getMessage();

      MessageChannel ftpChannel = context.getBean("ftpChannel", MessageChannel.class);
      File file = new File("C:\\test.txt");
      Message<File> fileMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file).build();
      ftpChannel.send(fileMessage);
      ((AbstractApplicationContext) context).close();
   }
}
```

2) And this is the **Beans.xml** configuration file in which I configure the FTP connection:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int-ftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.2.xsd">

    <bean id="helloWorld" class="it.myCompany.myProject.batch.HelloWorld">
       <property name="message" value="Hello World!"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ftpClientFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="MY HOST"/>
        <property name="username" value="USERNAME"/>
        <property name="password" value="PSWD"/>
        <property name="clientMode" value="0"/>
        <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
        <property name="bufferSize" value="10000"/>                 
    </bean>

<int:channel id="ftpChannel"/>

<!--  
<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter
                id="sendFileToServer"
                auto-create-directory="true"
                session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                remote-directory="/test"/>
-->

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="outFtpAdapter"
                                channel="ftpChannel"
                                session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                                remote-directory="/home/myFolder"/>



</beans>
```

From my local Windows machine (performin it from Eclipse) it works fine and the selected file is putted into the **/home/myFolder** directory on my FTP server.

The problem is that I have to perform it as an **runnable JAR file** on a Linux machine.

So I have simply change this line of the **MainApp** class:

```
File file = new File("C:\\test.txt");
```

in this way:

```
File file = new File("/home/myUser/provaVPC.txt");
```

(in this way I simply select a specific .txt file into the Linux filesystem).

And then I exported my project as a **runnable JAR file** (so it contains all the required dependencies needed to work).

So I put the obtained jar file into the Linux machine but when I try to perform it in this environment I obtain the following error message:

```
[maquilanti@jboss_svil ~]$ java -jar TestFtp.jar

Feb 15, 2016 4:25:58 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh

INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@490b8a8c: startup date [Mon Feb 15 16:25:58 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy

Feb 15, 2016 4:25:58 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions

INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]

Feb 15, 2016 4:25:59 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean loadProperties

INFO: Loading properties file from URL [jar:rsrc:spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]

Feb 15, 2016 4:25:59 PM org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationRegistrar registerHeaderChannelRegistry

INFO: No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.

Feb 15, 2016 4:26:00 PM org.springframework.integration.config.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor registerErrorChannel

INFO: No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.

Feb 15, 2016 4:26:00 PM org.springframework.integration.config.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor registerTaskScheduler

INFO: No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.

Feb 15, 2016 4:26:00 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean loadProperties

INFO: Loading properties file from URL [jar:rsrc:spring-integration-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]

Feb 15, 2016 4:26:00 PM org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler initialize

INFO: Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'

Feb 15, 2016 4:26:00 PM org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor start

INFO: Starting beans in phase 0

Feb 15, 2016 4:26:00 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer logComponentSubscriptionEvent

INFO: Adding {message-handler:outFtpAdapter} as a subscriber to the 'ftpChannel' channel

Feb 15, 2016 4:26:00 PM org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel adjustCounterIfNecessary

INFO: Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@490b8a8c.ftpChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).

Feb 15, 2016 4:26:00 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer start

INFO: started outFtpAdapter

Feb 15, 2016 4:26:00 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer logComponentSubscriptionEvent

INFO: Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel

Feb 15, 2016 4:26:00 PM org.springframework.integration.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel adjustCounterIfNecessary

INFO: Channel 'org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@490b8a8c.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).

Feb 15, 2016 4:26:00 PM org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer start

INFO: started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger

Your Message : Hello World!

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Error handling message for file [/home/maquilanti/provaVPC.txt -> provaVPC.txt]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/home/eds/provaVPC.txt.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to write to '/home/eds/provaVPC.txt.writing'. Server replied with: 500 Illegal PORT command.



        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate$1.doInSession(RemoteFileTemplate.java:320)

        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate$1.doInSession(RemoteFileTemplate.java:282)

        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:410)

        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:282)

        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:272)

        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.send(RemoteFileTemplate.java:264)

        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:142)

        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)

        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)

        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)

        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)

        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)

        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)

        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)

        at it.hp.miur.batch.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:23)

        ... 5 more

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/home/eds/provaVPC.txt.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to write to '/home/eds/provaVPC.txt.writing'. Server replied with: 500 Illegal PORT command.



        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:533)

        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.access$500(RemoteFileTemplate.java:59)

        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate$1.doInSession(RemoteFileTemplate.java:305)

        ... 19 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to write to '/home/eds/provaVPC.txt.writing'. Server replied with: 500 Illegal PORT command.



        at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.write(FtpSession.java:123)

        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(RemoteFileTemplate.java:505)

        ... 21 more
```

So it seems that, from this Linux environment, it can't send the file because the obtained exception is:

**Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/home/eds/provaVPC.txt.writing' while uploading the file; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to write to '/home/eds/provaVPC.txt.writing'. Server replied with: 500 Illegal PORT command.**

How is it possible if from the Windows environment works fine. I think that the problem is not in the **File** object creation from a textual file on the file system but it happens when this File object is sended a **Message** to my FTP server. But why? What can be the cause of this problem? How can I try to solve this issue? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch to passive mode, because DefaultFtpSessionFactory use active mode by default. In your config use [clientMode](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/ftp/session/AbstractFtpSessionFactory.html#setClientMode-int-) 2

Comment: mmm, I will try. But why from Windows development machine works fine?

Comment: This issue is related to firewall.